# GitLab CI Why this runner isn't doing the build?

Tags: git, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

When I push a new commit, I would like to start build from the runner, but I get this message :

> This build is stuck, because you don't have any active runners online with any of these tags assigned to them: dev
>
> Go to Runners page

I installed GitLab 8.15.2.

I created a basic project in C, a ".gitlab-ci.yml" file :

```
project1:
  tags:
    - dev
  script:
    - make
    - ./test
```

(If I remove the tag, I get almost the same message)

I created a specific runner :

```
root@debian:~# gitlab-ci-multi-runner register
Running in system-mode.
Please enter the gitlab-ci coordinator URL (e.g. https://gitlab.com/):
  http://127.0.0.1
Please enter the gitlab-ci token for this runner:
  XXX
Please enter the gitlab-ci description for this runner:
  [debian]: p1
Please enter the gitlab-ci tags for this runner (comma separated):
  dev
Registering runner... succeeded                     runner=XXX
Please enter the executor: kubernetes, docker, parallels, ssh, docker+machine, docker-ssh, shell, virtualbox, docker-ssh+machine:
  shell
Runner registered successfully. Feel free to start it, but if it's running already the config should be automatically reloaded!
root@debian:~# gitlab-ci-multi-runner verify
Running in system -mode.

Verifying runner... is alive                        runner=XXX
```

On /admin/runners, I can see it.

I don't understand what I'm missing...

Comment: Did you start the runner? `gitlab-ci-multi-runner start` or `gitlab-ci-multi-runner run`

Comment: No... `gitlab-ci-multi-runner run` make the build working, thank you a lot !

Comment: Nice! I'll put this as an answer.

Comment: i have an issue that gitlab-runner version must same as gitlab version, to install a specific version of GitLab Runner https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-repository.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You still have to start the runner:

Execute `gitlab-ci-multi-runner start` to start the service, or `gitlab-ci-multi-runner run` to run it directly in the terminal.

Comment: Have both on 2 computers still nothing :)

Comment: In my case 'gitlab-ci-multi-runner stop' and 'gitlab-ci-multi-runner start' helped.